# What is causing the 'Alias parsing was not enabled' error in Psych while upgrading Rails to 6.0.6.1 and how can it be resolved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, psych, rails-upgrade, ruby-upgrade

**Alias parsing was not enabled**
getting psych error when upgrading rails from 5.2 to 6.0.6.1

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8@reports2/gems/psych-5.1.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:432:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Cannot load database configuration:

Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass `aliases: true` to `Psych::load` or `Psych::safe_load`. (Psych::AliasesNotEnabled)
```

please provide some solid solution for this error.

**my changes** 
**in environment.rb file** 
require_relative 'application' 
**in development.rb file** 
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store 
**in asset.rb** 
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules') 
**in application.rb** 
require_relative 'boot' 
config.load_defaults 6.0

Comment: I just upgraded a big application from 5.max to Rails 6.max and didn't see this issue.  It's likely with a way you're loading stuff from a file.  The stack trace should give you a good indication on where this error is coming from.  What is the line that is causing it?

Comment: /home/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:432:in 'visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Cannot load 'Rails.application.database_configuration'

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue after upgrading from Rails 3.0.3 to Rails 7.1.2. How did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: I too would like to know if there is a solution. I'm getting the same error after upgrading from Rails 7.0.8 to Rails 7.1.2.