# Psych AliasesNotEnabled after upgrading Rails to latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, runtime-error, rails-upgrade

I had an application running on Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3. I upgraded Ruby to version 3.0.0 and Rails to 7.1.2. Now when I run "rails server", I have the following error message and the server is exiting:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/psych-5.1.1.1/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:432:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass` aliases: true`to`Psych::load`or`Psych::safe_load`. (Psych::AliasesNotEnabled)

Someone posted the same question here, [What is causing the 'Alias parsing was not enabled' error in Psych while upgrading Rails to 6.0.6.1 and how can it be resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76385038/what-is-causing-the-alias-parsing-was-not-enabled-error-in-psych-while-upgradi) but there was no answer.

EDIT:

It seems my error came from this call : APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]

I apparently found a way to solve it by using this : APP_CONFIG = Rails.application.config_for(:config)

Now having another error but it's another subject...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [now](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5140) you need to add `aliases: true`:

```rb
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(
  "#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml",
  aliases: true, # <- here
)[Rails.env]
```